# why my powershell try catch codes are printing only error?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

$MDservices = ""

$tempservices = ""

try{

```
$alerter = Get-Service Alerter

if($alerter.Status -eq 'Running'){

    $alerter = Out-String -InputObject $alerter.DisplayName

    $MDservices = $tempservices + $alerter

} else {

    continue

}
```

}

catch
{

```
 write "somethings wrong"
```

}

This is my powershell try catch codes.
I expect this output is write "somethings wrong" becaues my pc dosen't have 'Alerter' service
but it's output is printing error

What am i do guys? Help me:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely due your default $ErrorActionPreference value.

Try following :

```
try
{   $alerter = Get-Service Alerter -ErrorAction Stop
    if($alerter.Status -eq 'Running') {
        $alerter = Out-String -InputObject $alerter.DisplayName
        $MDservices = $tempservices + $alerter
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
}
catch
{   Write-Host "somethings wrong"
}
finally
{
    Write-Host "cleaning up ..."
}
```

Comment: Thanks your advice! I'll continue my coding refrence your code

Answer (score 2):

If the `try` block does not generate a terminating error, it will not move into the `Catch` block. This is controlled by `-ErrorAction` parameter. By default it uses `Continue`. So just change

```
# This will generate terminating error and move to Catch Block.
$alerter = Get-Service Alerter -ErrorAction Stop
```

Ref: [Try/Catch/Finally…doesn’t work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/#try-catch-finallydoesnt-work)